# Ember library causing "Binding Style Attributes" deprecation warning

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, filepicker

I'm trying to use the [ember-cli-file-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-file-picker) to load a file into my app for processing in the browser. It works but raises the following deprecation error

> WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site scripting
>   vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are properly escaped.
>   For more information, including how to disable this warning, see
>   http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_warning-when-binding-style-
>   attributes.
>
> [Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the
>   'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is
>   required to enable inline execution.

I'm thinking that this is because of

```
progressStyle: computed('progressValue', function() {
  var width = this.get('progressValue') || 0;

  return htmlSafe('width: ' + width + '%;');
})
```

in the library. I'm pretty new at ember, and am not positive that the library is safe, nor how to silence the deprecation warning using `SafeString` if it is. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSP issue.

You can disable this warning by editing your config/environment.js file:

Find:

```
ENV.contentSecurityPolicy = {
```

And edit the 'style-src' attribute to include 'unsafe-inline'

```
'style-src': "'self' 'unsafe-inline'",
```

Comment: That does silence the "Report Only" section, but not the "Warning: Binding style" part. Any way to remove both?

Comment: I think since its raised by the library it is an issue on their side. I'd raise a ticket here: https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-cli-file-picker . It looks like they need to use Ember.Handlebars.SafeString from here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/writing-helpers/

Comment: Just [submitted a ticket](https://github.com/funkensturm/ember-cli-file-picker/issues/7). Thanks!

Comment: FYI it's generally bad form to add 'unsafe-inline' like in this answer. It can leave you open to CSS injection. Anyway, it looks like the library has since fixed this problem in its 0.0.6 release.